# Is it possible to calculate all the possible salted hash values so that all the password will become useless?

Tags: hash, passwords

According to the mechanism of hash, which is a one-way calculation, can we calculate all the salted hash value to make the password useless?

For example, if we have something like

`salt = [possible combinations];
password = [possible combinations]`

Can we enumerate all the possibilities of salt as well as password and hash them to make a big table for reverse look-up?

Comment: Isn't this kind of like asking if we can count to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this is possible, and it has been done for very short salts, in this case the salt/password combination can be seen as just a longer password.

In reality you very soon reach a threshold, where todays and tomorrows computer won't be able calculate enough permutaions in reasonable time. In contrast to the passwords, salts should be random values and therefore one cannot take shortcuts with dictionaries.

So salts must have a minimum size, and if you choose a unique salt per password with 128-bit (BCrypt), then even for fast hash algorithms which can be calculated with 100Giga/sec one would expect about 5E19 years to find a match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was confusing on this problem for quiet a long time, quite dummy=.=. So the salted password is a method to increase the time and space complexity of brute-force calculation, which, given known technology, cannot be solved in reasonable time. Thus, it makes cracking no sense. Assume i'm 20 years old now, and i'm trying to crack Trump's twitter password, i might success when i'm 80, but it makes no sense to have the password at that time

Comment: @MetaKevin - You nearly got it. The salt does not increase time for brute-forcing a single password, because it is stored together with the hash in plaintext. But it indeed prevents building of one universal rainbow table, containing all salt/password combinations. You could still build rainbow tables for each password, but you would get only one password per rainbow-table, and not all at once. BTW you don't really want to get 50'000'000'000'000'000'000 years old, do you? Maybe you want to have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) for more information.

Comment: **Wonderful！Thanks Again!**